# Words generated from Text.similar() and ContextIndex.similar_words() in NLTK sorted by frequency?

Tags: python, nltk

I'm using these two functions to find similar words and they return different lists. I'm wondering if these functions are sorted by most to least frequent association?

Answer (score 4):

[`ContextIndex.similar_words(word)`](http://nltk.org/_modules/nltk/text.html#ContextIndex.similar_words) calculates the similarity score for each word as the sum of the products of frequencies in each context.
[`Text.similar()`](http://nltk.org/_modules/nltk/text.html#Text.similar) simply counts the number of unique contexts the words share.

`similar_words()` seems to contain a bug in NLTK 2.0. See the definition in [nltk/text.py](http://nltk.org/_modules/nltk/text.html#ContextIndex.similar_words):

```
def similar_words(self, word, n=20):
    scores = defaultdict(int)
    for c in self._word_to_contexts[self._key(word)]:
        for w in self._context_to_words[c]:
            if w != word:
                print w, c, self._context_to_words[c][word], self._context_to_words[c][w]
                scores[w] += self._context_to_words[c][word] * self._context_to_words[c][w]
    return sorted(scores, key=scores.get)[:n]
```

The returned word list should be sorted in descending order of similarity score. Replace the return statement with:

```
return sorted(scores, key=scores.get)[::-1][:n]
```

In `similar()`, the call to `similar_words()` is commented out, perhaps due to this bug.

```
def similar(self, word, num=20):
    if '_word_context_index' not in self.__dict__:
        print 'Building word-context index...'
        self._word_context_index = ContextIndex(self.tokens,
                                                filter=lambda x:x.isalpha(),
                                                key=lambda s:s.lower())

#   words = self._word_context_index.similar_words(word, num)

    word = word.lower()
    wci = self._word_context_index._word_to_contexts
    if word in wci.conditions():
        contexts = set(wci[word])
        fd = FreqDist(w for w in wci.conditions() for c in wci[w]
                      if c in contexts and not w == word)
        words = fd.keys()[:num]
        print tokenwrap(words)
    else:
        print "No matches"
```

*Note: in a `FreqDist`, unlike a `dict`, `keys()` returns a sorted list.*

**Example:**

```
import nltk

text = nltk.Text(word.lower() for word in nltk.corpus.brown.words())
text.similar('woman')

similar_words = text._word_context_index.similar_words('woman')
print ' '.join(similar_words)
```

**Output:**

```
man day time year car moment world family house boy child country
job state girl place war way case question   # Text.similar()

#man ('a', 'who') 9 39   # output from similar_words(); see following explanation
#girl ('a', 'who') 9 6
#[...]

man number time world fact end year state house way day use part
kind boy matter problem result girl group   # ContextIndex.similar_words()
```

`fd`, the frequency distribution in `similar()`, is a tally of the number of contexts for each word:

```
fd = [('man', 52), ('day', 30), ('time', 30), ('year', 28), ('car', 24), ('moment', 24), ('world', 23) ...]
```

For each word in each context, `similar_words()` calculates the sum of the product of the frequencies:

```
man ('a', 'who') 9 39  # 'a man who' occurs 39 times in text;
                       # 'a woman who' occurs 9 times
                       # Similarity score for the context is the product:
                       #     score['man'] = 9 * 39
girl ('a', 'who') 9 6
writer ('a', 'who') 9 4
boy ('a', 'who') 9 3
child ('a', 'who') 9 2
dealer ('a', 'who') 9 2
...
man ('a', 'and') 6 11  # score += 6 * 11
...
man ('a', 'he') 4 6    # score += 4 * 6
...
[49 more occurrences of 'man']
```

Comment: What is the difference between a *similarity score* and the value that arises from *distributional similarity*?

Comment: @mac389 see my expanded answer

Comment: Thanks for your work. At the risk of hijacking this question, what do you mean by "tally of contexts"? I understand that `similar()` is a sum and `similar_words()` is a sumproduct. Sum, sumproduct of what though? I thought both found all words that shared the same immediately flanking words. So, why would you ever sum that? I'm clearly missing something.

Comment: In the example, there are 52 distinct contexts shared by 'man' and 'woman' (the target word). `similar()` would give 'man' a score of 52. `similar_words()` counts the number of instances of each context, e.g. 39 x 'a man who', 11 x 'a man and', etc., and does the same for 'woman' (9 x 'a woman who', 6 x 'a woman and', etc.), then calculates the similarity score as the sum-product: 39x9 + 11x6 + 6x4 + ...